# getting text from a textbox with a 'static' variable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtextfield

I want to get the text from the textfield contractNo. The current value is imported from another class. However, when I set the value of the String variable contract from the content of the textfield contractNo, the error states: "non-static variable contract cannot be referenced from a static context, non-static variable contractNo cannot be referenced from a static context"

The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(final String user, final String cNo) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EditContract.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EditContract.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EditContract.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EditContract.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EditContract editC = new EditContract();
            editC.contractNo.setText(cNo);
            editC.encoder.setText(user);
            editC.setVisible(true);

            fillData();

        }
         private void fillData() {

            try {


                contract = contractNo.getText();
                String sql = "Select engager, contactInfo, eventDate, eventtime, address, menu, contract, referred "
                        + "from kusinanikambal.contracts where contractno = 1234";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            }
                catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken and needs several significant fixes.

- You should not try to access class fields directly regardless. If you need to get the state of a class's field, then call a public method on the viable instance of that class. Here it would likely be a field of your EditContract object, I'm guessing, and if so, give EditContract a public method that exposes the content of its JTextField.
- If EditContract is not a modal dialog, even if you could get your field correctly, your code will not work, since you're then extracting the data immediately on showing the GUI before the user has had a chance to enter anything. You appear to be ignoring that Java GUI's are event driven, meaning that you should extract information from your GUI in an event, often the ActionListener of a menu or button. In other words, your `fillData()` method smells like it does not belong where you're putting it.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Filldata is actually supposed to execute upon initialization of the program.

- Then if this were true, what value should the contractNo JTextField hold, since the method is being run before the user has interacted with the program?
- And if it needs to run at program start, why not put it in your EditContract's constructor?

---

**Edit 2**

To clarify, if my GUI class had a JTextField and I needed access to it from elsewhere, I'd do something like:

```
public class MyGui {
  private JTextField myField = new JTextField(10);

  public String getFieldText() {
    return myField.getText();
  }

  // ....

}
```

Then later other classes can call the `getFieldText()` method on MyGui instances if they need to access the text.

Comment: Filldata is actually supposed to execute upon initialization of the program.

Comment: I implemented your recommendation but it still shows the same error.

Comment: @user3209957: Then you're still calling it in a static way! Don't do that -- call the public method that you've created on an object. You would do well to read almost any beginning Java book first 1-3 chapters to learn about static and instance. If you need further help, then consider [editing your original post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24802523/edit), adding your newest code to the bottom, and adding any and all full error messages.

Comment: @user3209957: also, are you calling the code from the class's constructor as I recommended? Also can you provide more detail as to what over all problem you're trying to solve -- what is the code supposed to be doing?